# Providing UI notifications when the ViewModel detects a file permissions issue

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, mvvm

Being a neophyte in C#, WPF and MVVM, I am refactoring my first app prototype from a kludge that was almost fully implemented in the code-behind to an MVVM pattern.  I have everything working nicely: data binding, commands, etc.  Almost everything has been moved to its correct location but I am running into a little bit of an issue trying to figure out how I should handle files.

My model supports a chunk of data that is sent to and read from a remote electronic device.  That data is transformed in the VM and exchanged with the V via binding.  The user may optionally select to stream output to a CSV.  This can be done via an OpenFileDialog or by entering the file name directly in the text box.

I am relatively certain about two considerations (correct me if you disagree):

1) It's acceptable to handle the OpenFileDialog in the V and send the filename to the MV via binding.  I've seen this answered in other discussions.

2) I'll implement a filehandler class that will open the file, check permissions, format the CSV record, etc.

What I am unsure about is how the file checking should occur.  If a file is locked, or has not been selected, or already exists, how can this be communicated to the V so that the user is notified?  In my first cut at the app, I simply implemented this logic in the code-behind, which does not seem correct:

```
    private bool CSVReady()
    {
        if (filenameTextbox.Text == "<no file selected>")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an output file.");
            return false;
        }

        if (File.Exists(filenameTextbox.Text))
        {
            var r = MessageBox.Show("File already exists.  Append to it?",
                    "File Warning",
                    MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                    MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            if (r == MessageBoxResult.No)
                return false;

            try
            {
                File.OpenWrite(filenameTextbox.Text).Close();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File is already open.  Please close it.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else // file does not exist, create it and initialize the column labels.
        {
            if ((MessageBox.Show("File does not exist.  Create it?", "File Creation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning) ==
                MessageBoxResult.No))
                return false;

            File.Create(filenameTextbox.Text).Close();
            File.AppendAllText( // Blah blah blah
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Good use of the word 'neophyte'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have correctly data bound an instance of your view model to your view's `DataContext` property, then you can access your view model from your view's code behind simply, like this:

```
...
DialogResult result = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK) filePath = fileDialog.FileName;
...
ViewModel viewModel = (ViewModel)DataContext; //  <--------
viewModel.DoSomethingWithNewFilePath(filePath);
```

---

UPDATE >>>

> What I am unsure about is how the file checking should occur. If a file is locked, or has not been selected, or already exists, how can this be communicated to the V so that the user is notified?

The way that you have written your file checking process is fine as far as MVVM goes. You're not breaking any rules. It's the 'quick' way to implement such functionality, but of course, there are different levels of coding quality.

In my applications, I have `xxxManager` classes that perform a variety of functionality for me... some might call them service classes. As such, I have a `WindowManager` class that handles all `Window` related tasks, including showing `MessageBox`es and various dialogs. The reason for this is that I can interface these classes and provide mock implementations for testing, so that the tests don't really open `Window`s that need someone to close.

If you're not testing and not likely to want to change or add a web interface, then you really don't need that level of separation. If however, you are working on a business application, then it is generally considered good practice to separate the various concerns of the application into different folders or projects; data access, data manipulation, services and UI.

I also have a `HardDriveManager` class that enables me to perform all of those `System.IO` functions from the view model without having to add `using`s for the relevant dlls. So the answer is that what you're doing is ok, but you could split out the different functionality into different helper classes.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant with point "1)" above. That is exactly what I am doing when the user presses the "Set File" button. What I am not sure about are the special cases I listed in the code above that check for whether a file has been selected, whether it exists and is locked.